# complexity of given code?

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to find out the complexity of the given code below as a function of the problem size n.

```
sum = 0;

if (EVEN(n))
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (i%2 == 0)
        O(logn)
      else
        sum ++;
else
    sum = sum + n;
```

Here is my answer but I am not sure if I did it correct.

`sum=0; is equal to O(1)`.

The first if else loop consists of a nested for loop, with a nested if statement.  So it would be n times the code inside the for loop.  Since its if statement and will be either block 1 or block 2.  Since `O(logn)` is slower than sum ++ which is `O(1)` it is `O(logn)`.  So it is `O(n)*O(logn)`.

Hence the final answer would be `O(1) + n*O(logn)`.  Is this correct??

Comment: I was wondering about the best case and average case. Here is my explanation, does this sound correct? Now let’s consider the best case, where n is not even. Since n is not even the code inside the first if statement will not execute. So we need to look at the code sum = sum +n. This is running time of O(1). Adding it up it would be O(1) + O(1) = 2*O(1), which is equal to O(1). So the best case would be O(1). The average is O(n*log(n))+ O(1) / 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, O(nlog(n)) would be the complexity.

Comment: I was wondering about the best case and average case.  Here is my explanation, does this sound correct?




Now let’s consider the best case, where n is not even.  Since n is not even the code inside the first if statement will not execute. 

So we need to look at the code sum = sum +n.  This is running time of O(1).  

Adding it up it would be O(1) + O(1) = 2*O(1), which is equal to O(1).  

So the best case would be O(1).

The average is   O(n*log(n))+ O(1) / 2

Answer (score 2):

Yeap seems to be correct if you're talking about worst running time. You can rewrite `O(n)*O(logn)` as `O(n*log(n))`.